# Sliding expandable inline menu

Tags: css, menu, inline, sliding, expandable

I had a concept for a simple (in appearance) menu which expands and retracts submenus using **only CSS**.

This is what have conceptualized:

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">main one</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">main two</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">main three</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have coded the basic framework above (ignore lack of classes, ids, pipe symbols etc.) using nested unordered lists, but I'm having trouble keeping everything inline. All lists are `list-style-type: none` and all list items are floated left.

Also, I don't know how to prevent the word wrapping so that the whole list item is moved to a new line as a whole instead of being broken in two.

Additionally, what property could I use in conjunction with the transition property to make the nested lists slide out on mouse click?

Comment: Is that font Century Gothic? :P I like your color choice. +1.

Comment: Indeed it is. Probably my favourite font to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two methods:

**1.** Using `a:focus + ul` (`a:active + ul` for IE) to make the menu expand on click.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3635623)

*Advantages*:

- it has excellent browser support: works as intended even in IE8; somewhat in IE7, though you need to hover off the link to see the 
  menu expanding;
- preserves your current HTML structure, you just need to add `tabindex='1'` to the links you want to trigger an action when clicked (like an expanding submenu)

*Disadvantages*:

- you cannot have multiple submenus in the 'expanded' state at once;
- it is not persistent; this means that once you click somewhere else in the page, the link that expanded the submenu loses focus => the submenu colapses;

*How it works*:

- `a:focus` selects the link that has focus (a link gets focus after being clicked and it keeps focus until something else is clicked)
- `a:focus + ul` selects the unordered list (`ul`) that is a sibling of the link that has focus (after being clicked in this case) and comes right after it (= there is no other element between them) in the HTML - see this: [**adjacent sibling combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)
- `a:focus + ul li` selects the list item that is a descendant of the unordered list described above
- `a:focus + ul a` selects the link that is a descendant of the unordered list described above

---

**2.** Using the checkbox hack.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3636352)

*Advantages*:

- you can have multiple submenus expanded at once;
- it is persistent; expanded menus don't collapse when you click somewhere else on the page;

*Disadvantages*:

- you need to change your HTML structure;
- doesn't work in IE8 or older;

*How it works*:

- `input[type=checkbox]:checked` selects checked checkboxes; the checkboxes are hidden here (set `display: none` on them), but clicking on a `label` checks the checkbox whose `id` is the same as the value of the `for` attribute of the `label` that was clicked;
- `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul` selects the unordered list that is a sibling (not necessarily adjacent) of the checked checkbox - see this: [**general sibling combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

Comment: Yes, that's awesome. It's very close to what I have in mind, but is it possible to make it so that each submenu is a toggle, rather than only being able to have one out at a time? Also, could you make it so that the height remains constant while it slides out (removing the height leaves that little bit showing)?

Could you also explain how the `a:focus + ul a` selector works?

Comment: Yes, to the first question, but using the checkbox hack, not this menu structure. As for the `height`, this http://dabblet.com/gist/3635623/f69409ee9ee7e6613b7ed098a6a82b6a5445ed07 is the best I can come up with right now. I'll expand my answer with a few more details about the `:focus`/ `:active` method and the checkbox hack.

Comment: Well I know what `:focus` and `:active` do, but I guess I was just confused at the + symbol. I had never seen it used before.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some explanations and another demo.

Answer (score 0):

set main one child to

```
display:none;
```

and on hover of main one

set them to

```
display:block;
```

Comment: The display property isn't handled by any transition. It's the obvious answer I grant you, but the sliding animation is crucial.

Comment: have you any example on any other website so i can help you better

Comment: where u see that sliding animation 
without knowing what u want how can i help you

Comment: I do know what I want, but all I can do to help you help me is visualize it above and explain the functionality. If I had a working example to show you, I would just get the answer from that.